# Change font color of scrbook titlepage

Tags: color, titles, koma-script

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, breaklinks=true, pdftex=true, raiselinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\color{red}
\title{MainTitle}
\author{"author"}
\subject{Subject} \publishers{Publisher}
\titlehead{Publisher\\City}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I can set colors of everything except the subject and the title to red. Can somebody give me a tip on how to set the size of the text and the font color of the title and subject too, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\addtokomafont` for `title` and `subject`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{subject}{\color{red}}
\addtokomafont{title}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\color{red}
\title{MainTitle}
\author{"author"}
\subject{Subject} \publishers{Publisher}
\titlehead{Publisher\\City}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I have a naive question: what is the difference between `setkomafont` and `addtokomafont`? In other words, when do I need to use one of them?

Answer (score 4):

The `KOMA-Script` package provides the commands `\setkomafont` and `\addtokomafont` to modify the font of certain elements.

I expanded your example with two `\addtokomafont` directives which make the title and subject go red:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, breaklinks=true, pdftex=true, raiselinks=true]{hyperref}

\addtokomafont{title}{\color{red}}
\addtokomafont{subject}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\color{red}
\title{MainTitle}
\author{"author"}
\subject{Subject} \publishers{Publisher}
\titlehead{Publisher\\City}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The syntax and working principle of the commands as well as what styles are influenced by them is explained in the `KOMA-Script` manual, just search for "addtokomafont" or "setkomafont".

By the way: you could also use this mechanism to set your other titlepage information to red instead of doing it by the `\color{red}` command in the text.